# QGIS SAGA Gaussian Filter brings error when run

Tags: qgis, raster, saga, filter

Every time I run the SAGA Gaussian Filter tool, I get an error. I am trying to filter a raster file indicating a risk index (GeoTIFF, 32-bit float) in order to smooth it. The log message I get is shown below, but I cannot work out what the problem is.[image]

This is the log:

```
Processing algorithm…
AlgorithmDialog
Input parameters:
{ 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/hp/Desktop/COOPI/GIS_Data/REFINED_DATABASE/Population_and_Vulnerability/Mangochi_Flood_Risk_Vuln_Index_plus_FloodRPFreq.tif', 'SIGMA' : 1, 'MODE' : 1, 'RADIUS' : 3, 'RESULT' : 'C:/Users/hp/Desktop/COOPI/GIS_Data/REFINED_DATABASE/Population_and_Vulnerability/Mangochi_Flood_Risk_Vuln_Index_plus_FloodRPFreq_SAGA_GausFilt_sd1_circ_rad3_n1.tif' }

io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_02b6ceef88f2494b95a282c31bcf383f/59b304d5140f44859191da5fe4d5a355/MangochiFloodRiskVulnIndexplusFloodRPFreq.sgrd" -FILES "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\COOPI\GIS_Data\REFINED_DATABASE\Population_and_Vulnerability\Mangochi_Flood_Risk_Vuln_Index_plus_FloodRPFreq.tif"
grid_filter "Gaussian Filter" -INPUT "C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_02b6ceef88f2494b95a282c31bcf383f/59b304d5140f44859191da5fe4d5a355/MangochiFloodRiskVulnIndexplusFloodRPFreq.sgrd" -SIGMA 1 -MODE 1 -RADIUS 3 -RESULT "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/COOPI/GIS_Data/REFINED_DATABASE/Population_and_Vulnerability/Mangochi_Flood_Risk_Vuln_Index_plus_FloodRPFreq_SAGA_GausFilt_sd1_circ_rad3_n1.tif"

C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>set SAGA=C:/OSGEO4~1/apps\saga-ltr

C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>set SAGA_MLB=C:/OSGEO4~1/apps\saga-ltr\modules

C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>PATH=C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qgis\bin;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\grass\grass-7.4.0\lib;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\grass\grass-7.4.0\bin;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python36\Scripts;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\qt5\bin;C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python27\Scripts;C:\OSGEO4~1\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\system32\WBem;C:/OSGEO4~1/apps\saga-ltr;C:/OSGEO4~1/apps\saga-ltr\modules

C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>saga_cmd io_gdal 0 -TRANSFORM 1 -RESAMPLING 3 -GRIDS "C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_02b6ceef88f2494b95a282c31bcf383f/59b304d5140f44859191da5fe4d5a355/MangochiFloodRiskVulnIndexplusFloodRPFreq.sgrd" -FILES "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\COOPI\GIS_Data\REFINED_DATABASE\Population_and_Vulnerability\Mangochi_Flood_Risk_Vuln_Index_plus_FloodRPFreq.tif"
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.3.2 (64 bit)

____________________________
library path: C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\saga-ltr\modules\
library name: io_gdal
library : GDAL/OGR
tool : Import Raster
author : O.Conrad (c) 2007 (A.Ringeler)
processors : 4 [4]
____________________________



Parameters


Grids: No objects
Files: "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\COOPI\GIS_Data\REFINED_DATABASE\Population_and_Vulnerability\Mangochi_Flood_Risk_Vuln_Index_plus_FloodRPFreq.tif"
Select from Multiple Bands:
Alphanumeric Sorting: yes
Transformation: yes
Resampling: B-Spline Interpolation


loading: C:\Users\hp\Desktop\COOPI\GIS_Data\REFINED_DATABASE\Population_and_Vulnerability\Mangochi_Flood_Risk_Vuln_Index_plus_FloodRPFreq.tif



Driver: GTiff

Bands: 1

Rows: 221

Columns: 288



Transformation:

x' = 687355.812500 + x * 503.662896 + y * 0.000000

y' = 8508414.293103 + x * 0.000000 + y * -503.706897


loading: Mangochi_Flood_Risk_Vuln_Index_plus_FloodRPFreq



warning: top-to-bottom and left-to-right cell sizes differ.
Difference: 0.044001

using cellsize: 503.662896






C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>saga_cmd grid_filter "Gaussian Filter" -INPUT "C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_02b6ceef88f2494b95a282c31bcf383f/59b304d5140f44859191da5fe4d5a355/MangochiFloodRiskVulnIndexplusFloodRPFreq.sgrd" -SIGMA 1 -MODE 1 -RADIUS 3 -RESULT "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/COOPI/GIS_Data/REFINED_DATABASE/Population_and_Vulnerability/Mangochi_Flood_Risk_Vuln_Index_plus_FloodRPFreq_SAGA_GausFilt_sd1_circ_rad3_n1.tif"
____________________________

##### ## ##### ##
### ### ## ###
### # ## ## #### # ##
### ##### ## # #####
##### # ## ##### # ##
____________________________

SAGA Version: 2.3.2 (64 bit)

____________________________
library path: C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\saga-ltr\modules\
library name: grid_filter
library : Filter
tool : Gaussian Filter
author : Copyrights (c) 2003 by Andre Ringeler
processors : 4 [4]
____________________________

Load grid: C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_02b6ceef88f2494b95a282c31bcf383f/59b304d5140f44859191da5fe4d5a355/MangochiFloodRiskVulnIndexplusFloodRPFreq.sgrd...




Parameters


Grid system: 503.662896; 221x 288y; 687607.643948x 8363598.560345y
Grid: MangochiFloodRiskVulnIndexplusFloodRPFreq
Filtered Grid: Filtered Grid
Standard Deviation: 1.000000
Search Mode: Circle
Search Radius: 3






C:\OSGEO4~1\bin>exit
Execution completed in 5.72 seconds
Results:
{'RESULT': 'C:/Users/hp/Desktop/COOPI/GIS_Data/REFINED_DATABASE/Population_and_Vulnerability/Mangochi_Flood_Risk_Vuln_Index_plus_FloodRPFreq_SAGA_GausFilt_sd1_circ_rad3_n1.tif'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.
C:/Users/hp/Desktop/COOPI/GIS_Data/REFINED_DATABASE/Population_and_Vulnerability/Mangochi_Flood_Risk_Vuln_Index_plus_FloodRPFreq_SAGA_GausFilt_sd1_circ_rad3_n1.tif
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```